# Gitlab CI\CD Error: Failed to create container volume for /builds/root Unable to load image

Tags: docker, gitlab, continuous-deployment, gitlab-ci-runner

I've installed the Gitlab local server and also install the Gitlab-runner and everything needs to use the CI/CD tools. After that When I run the CI/CD tools to build and deploy the project, it makes build failed.

Error detail:

```
Using Docker executor with image alpine:latest ... 

ERROR: Failed to
create container volume for /builds/root Unable to load image:
gitlab-runner-prebuilt: "open
/var/lib/gitlab-runner/gitlab-runner-prebuilt.tar.xz: no such file or
directory" 

ERROR: Preparation failed: Unable to load image:
gitlab-runner-prebuilt: "open
/var/lib/gitlab-runner/gitlab-runner-prebuilt.tar.xz: no such file or
directory"
```

[image]

**What is the problem and how can I resolve it?**

Comment: @Admintabar welcome to the DevOps SE site! Please share if possible your GitLab runner configuration ```/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a volume mounted with gitlab-runner-prebuilt.tar.xz? Your error log makes it seem like it can't find the file when it executes.